# Assign date in salesforce.

Tags: salesforce

I have written a batch job. In this batch job i have a condition to take date > = 1/1/2012
I am not able to give the date in the query. can you please help me.

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

```
    system.debug('Inside start');

    //date mydate = date.valueof(1/1/2012);
    return Database.getQueryLocator('select  name from opportunity');
}
```

I have given it in 2 ways 
1st is :
took the date into a date field and give the condition as date >= :mydate 
(shows an error in debug log as Invalid date: 0 )
and 
2nd way when i gave the date their itself as date >=: 1/1/2012
(it shows as error in debug log as unexpected token: / )

can you please help me

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must follow the proper date format

```
YYYY-MM-DD

select name from opportunity where mydate >= 2012-01-01
```

More information [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)